# ClassNotFoundException in HoloEverywhere when using MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-holo-everywhere

I want to add a map as a header to a ListFragment. Everything seemed to worked fine except when the device orientation changes.

The ListFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_header, null);      
    mMapView = (MapView) mHeader.findViewById(R.id.map);

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = mMapView.getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }      
    }

    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {              
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);                       

    String[] array = new String[] {"Android", "Android"};

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, array));
}
```

The error:

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView$SavedState, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView$SavedState
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.i906.mpt/com.i906.mpt.Main}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView$SavedState
```

The problem won't occur if I changed to `mMapView.onCreate(null);` but the map will reload everytime the orientation changes. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks.